# How do I force Ghost's admin page to be server over SSL when ghost is installed in a subdirectory?

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy, ghost-blog

I am using Ghost as a blogging platform and nginx as a reverse proxy for ghost as detailed in the documentation. Ghost is installed in a subdirectory and is served over the domain http://example.com/blog whereas the static website is served over example.com

I have set up SSL on my server and want to serve the ghost login page (example.com/blog/ghost) over SSL while serving the rest of the pages over normal HTTP. However if I use `forceAdminSSL:true` and try to go to `http://example.com/blog/ghost` it should automatically redirect me to `https://example.com/blog/ghost`. Instead I'm redirected to `https://example.com/ghost` and end up with `404` error. The only work around I have found that works is to use `foreAdminSSL:{redirect:false}` which is clumsy because then I have to manually type https in the address bar instead of http.

How do I server Ghost Admin panel over ssl while ghost is installed in a subdirectory? I guess this has something to do with configuration in nginx.

My nginx config block

```
    server {
     listen       80;
     listen 443 ;
     server_name  *.example.com;
     server_name  example.com;
     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.key;

     location ^~/blog {
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2786;
             proxy_redirect off;
     }


    location / {
            root "/home/ubuntu/somedirectory/";
            index index.html;
    }
```

Comment: appending $uri to proxy_pass also does not work. neither do the plethors of regex I tried (or maybe I wrote some broken ones)

Answer (score -1):

I think you haven't entered the config URL while setting up Ghost correctly.

You can do this by running the following commands:

`ghost config URL https://my-domain.com/blog/`

`ghost restart`

If this doesn't solve the problem, you can check out a detailed tutorial, solving this issue, on my blog [here](https://snpranav.com/blog/ghost-in-subdirectory-over-ssl/?utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow.com)